# Assigning param value from WP shortcode to variable

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I need to assign one of the parameters of a Wordpress shortcode to a variable.

How do grab it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$myvar = do_shortcode('[shortcode option1="value1" option2="value2"]');
```

Comment: I'm looking to grab the value of option1